# can we modify wordpress plugin version value to avoid update warning?

Tags: plugins, upgrade, compatibility

Since plugin updates might bring some unexpected issues to the compatibilies.

Is it recommended to modify plugin version value
to fool the wordpress plugin update system if priority is to turn off plugin out-of-date warnings from wordpress backend ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `site_transient_update_plugins` hook to disable plugin updates.

```
function filter_plugin_updates( $value ) {
    unset( $value->response['plugin_folder/plugin_name.php'] );
    return $value;
}
add_filter( 'site_transient_update_plugins', 'filter_plugin_updates' );
```

Comment: /*
 e.g.  adding below function  in any plugin's root php file to stop showing plugin upgrade alert is tested working
*/
add_filter('site_transient_update_plugins', 'remove_update_notification');
function remove_update_notification($value) {
 unset($value->response[ plugin_basename(__FILE__) ]);
 return $value;
}

Comment: I would suggest to put it in your functions, rather than modifying your plugin.

Answer (score 1):

We've used this plugin with a great deal of success:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/stops-core-theme-and-plugin-updates/

It allows you to selectively switch off individual updates for the core, plugins, drop-ins and themes; or switch off updates for the whole lot.

It also blocks update warnings and notices, without you having to mess with your code.